# Run a concatenated string as a command within a Bash script

Tags: bash, variables

I'm trying to count the number of files with different extensions in `/foo/`.
**case 1** works as expected, but more flexible situations such as **case 2** or **case 3** don't work as expected.

File `test.sh`

```
# case 1
vista=$(find /foo/*.zip -atime -1)
echo "$vista" | wc -l

# case 2
vista=$(find /foo/*)

echo "$vista.zip -atime -1" | wc -l

# case 3
echo "$vista.xz -atime -1" | wc -l
```

Output:

```
./test.sh 
187
4566
4566
```

I suspect the problem is that for example `echo "$vista.zip -atime -1"` from **case 2** runs first `find /foo/*` before appending the string `zip -atime -1`, but I don't know how to do it right.

Comment: See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: See [Is it OK for users to edit the accepted answer into the question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262806/is-it-ok-for-users-to-edit-the-accepted-answer-into-their-question). For a Community Wiki answer (which isn't owned by any individual but open for anyone to edit with no individual getting rep points / credit), feel free to add your refinements to that answer itself.

Comment: Following @Charles Duffy's advise, a solution with functions is:

    find_under_foo() { find /foo/*"$1" "${@:2}"; }
    find_under_foo zip -atime -1 | wc -l

Comment: Also, `vista=$(find /foo/*)` doesn't do anything like storing a command in the variable, it runs the command and stores *its output* in the variable. So it might set `vista` to something like "`/foo/file1\n/foo/file2`" (where the `\n` represents an actual newline character). Then `echo "$vista.zip -atime -1" | wc -l` expands to `echo "/foo/file1\n/foo/file2.zip -atime -1" | wc -l` which isn't even slightly close to what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Code should never be stored in strings (unless using `printf %q` to generate `eval`-safe versions of variables, and then using `eval` at runtime). Use either an array (for dynamically-constructed content) or a function.

The former:

```
find_cmd=( find /foo/* )
"${find_cmd[@]}" -atime -1 | wc -l
```

The latter:

```
find_under_foo() { find /foo/* "$@"; }
find_under_foo -atime -1 | wc -l
```